# Failed to set locale. Fix your system

Tags: opensuse, locale, yast

A 32-bit server with openSUSE Tumbleweed:

While logging in, I received this warning:

> /usr/bin/manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct

To fix the above error, I run these commands to modify the system language and time, but I get errors:

```
> sudo yast2 language
[sudo] password for root: 
Failed to set locale. Fix your system.
Failed to set locale. Fix your system.
```

Also:

```
> sudo yast2 timezone
[sudo] password for root: 
Failed to set locale. Fix your system.
Failed to set locale. Fix your system.
```

I couldn't figure out the cause. Does anyone have a suggestion?

### Update

Locale output:

```
> locale 
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

Another output:

```
> locale -a
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
C.utf8
POSIX
aa_DJ
aa_DJ.utf8
aa_ER
aa_ER@saaho
aa_ET
af_ZA
af_ZA.utf8
agr_PE
ak_GH
am_ET
an_ES
an_ES.utf8

# ... it' a long list
```

### Update

Adding these lines to `~/.profile` didn't fix the problem, even after logging out or even reboot:

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

#### New observation

1. Log in to the server directly/physically: no warning is thrown
2. Log in to the server by SSH from a Linux laptop (openSUSE Leap 15.1): no warning is thrown
3. Log in to the server by SSH from MacBook laptop: this warning is thrown:

> /usr/bin/manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct

Comment: Run `locale` to see the current values for each locale category. Run `locale -a` to see all the (currently) valid values. Some distributions may require installing a localization/language package or running a command to create the locale files for a particular locale before it can be used, as having all the possible locale files available might consume a lot of disk space, and you're normally likely to use just one or only a few locales anyway.

Comment: Is this behaviour for a certain user or for all users? And what is your shell? Dependent on this, find out where the locale setting takes place (line `/etc/profile` or `~/.profile` or `~/.zshrc` or the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/openSUSE/comments/n6v2yw/failed_to_set_locale_fix_your_system/gxgc65y?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

> Ah, well that explains it. SSH forwards your locale along with the
> connection. So your Mac is asking for a locale which is not available
> on your Linux box.
>
> Either change your Mac locale to something consistent or change your
> Mac SSH settings to not forward locale:
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609371/how-do-not-pass-locale-through-ssh

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this with a few steps for some Raspberry Pis that I was sshing to.

1. I commented out `en_GB.UTF-8` in `/etc/locale.gen` and uncommented `en_US.UTF-8`.
2. I added the lines `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` and `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` to `/etc/default/locale`. You may need to add more lines like this such as `LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8`.
3. I ran `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`.
4. Finally, I ran `sudo locale-gen`.

If you run `locale` after these steps you shouldn't see any warnings and you should see `en_US.UTF-8` for all of the fields except maybe `LANG` and `LANGUAGE`. You can change these manually with `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and `export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8`.